# How to view a .rar file content remotely in a shared cPanel server (hostgator)?

Tags: ssh, rar, cpanel

I've tried using `unrar` via SSH but this command is not installed on my shared hostgator account.

Is there any application that does this in this kind of environment?

How to view a .rar file content remotely in a shared cPanel server?

Comment: Are you able to install any software? Is "apt install unrar" working?

Comment: Unfortunately I get `-jailshell: apt: command not found`...

Comment: Can you upload the unrar binary and then run it?

Comment: Would you know the correct link for this unrar and how to install it? Because I tried to download one from rarlabs for Linux, but I could not run it.

Comment: You could also try to download the source code instead and comile it. Maybe this will be useful: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/open-rar-file-or-extract-rar-files-under-linux-or-unix/